# Gray Shade inside a Check Box in MS Access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on an MS Access forms Application using VBA.

I have a form which has three check boxes and i am trying to add a new check box in the form. The Three check boxes , which are already present have the grey shade inside them.

What does it represent ? If any thing significant, how to acheive that .

I am linking my MS Access form objects with SQL Server

Please help on this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some documentation here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173460(v=office.11).aspx

That shading either means that a value has not been set, or that the "Triple State" property is set to True and the checkbox is displaying a null value (if "Triple State" is set to false, nulls display in the same manner as false - i.e., a clear checkbox).